# CSV data export with headers using PHP SQL server

Tags: php, csv, sql-server-2012, export-to-csv

I am trying to export the data from table on SQL server database to the CSV file. 
Data is formatted correctly and placed in each separate cells on the file. But the header is not formatted properly and is printed all on to one cell as a continuous stream.

Say you have a,b,c,d as headers : 
Header is printed as abcd on to the first cell and is not spitting out on to individual cells. how do we separate them out ?

Here is the code :

```
$flag = false;
if ($query) {
while( $data = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {


        foreach($data AS $key => $value){
                     if(!$flag) {

      // display field/column names as first row
                        $out .= implode("\t", array_keys($data)) . "\n";
                        //$out .= '"'.$head.'",';
                        $flag = true;
            }

        //If the character " exists, then escape it, otherwise the csv file will be invalid.
        $pos = strpos($value, '"');
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $value = str_replace('"', '\"', $value);
        }
        $out .= '"'.$value.'",';
    }
    $out .= "\n";

}
```

Comment: I would highly recommend using `fputcsv()` instead of your own implementation. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$out .= implode("\t", array_keys($data)) . "\n";
```

Is creating a tab separated line, but elsewhere you are using comma separated.

Probably you want to use comma's here as well:

```
$out .= implode(",", array_keys($data)) . "\n";
```